# On OS/X and Apache, localhost not resolving for some ports but not others

Tags: macos, apache2, localhost

I have an Apache setup with several virtual hosts, in order to test many copies of Drupal on my local machine, amongst other things (although it's not 100% essential to put Drupal at the root of its virtual host, various things get ugly if you don't).

Several of these have been working fine. But yesterday, I added a new one, and the system can't resolve it. In other words, the address http://127.0.0.1:7777 works fine, while the address http://localhost:7777 fails, with an HTTP error 324 (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE).

However, an identically set up vhost on localhost:7778 works just fine.

Any ideas?

Here is the relevant bit of Apache config:

```
<Directory "/Users/david/Sites/workspace/bachtrack7">
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>
Listen 7777
<Virtualhost *:7777>
   DocumentRoot /Users/david/Sites/workspace/bachtrack7
   Servername bachtrack7
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/Users/david/Sites/workspace/Sandbox">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
Listen 7778
<VirtualHost *:7778>
  DocumentRoot /Users/david/Sites/workspace/Sandbox
  Servername Sandbox
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Just to eliminate variables, try setting the other site running at 7778 to listen at 7777...Then try localhost 7777.  Now was it the site or the port causing the problem? The answer to that question might be enlightening...

Comment: @Techism Sorry if I sound ungrateful to have left this so late, but the e-mail alert didn't happen for some reason. Thanks for the reply, anyway. Sensible idea: it proves that the problem is associated with the port, not with the site. But I can't think of where.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a problem with your ports, there are several places where this can be happening (firewall, router, conflicting services, etc...)

The sensible solution?  Just pick a different port.